# Mod_Rewrite based on a database query

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm hoping to get the steps and concepts (as opposed to specific code) I need to use to solve the following problem.

I have a LAMP site that offers personal profiles that are currently served as **www.site.com/profile.php?id=user_id**.  Instead I want is **www.site.com/uniqueusername**.  I have read several threads on .htaccess mods but my case, I think, is a bit different.  What I need to accomplish is the following:

1. User requests www.site.com/username
2. Server queries a database and matches username to a corresponding user_id
3. Server sends back www.site.com/profile.php?id=correct user_id aliased (if that is the correct term) as www.site.com/username

The site currently uses an email address as a unique identifier for login which is matched to a user id.  I was hoping to add a username field during registration that would be used in the URL for the users profile page.

As I said previously, any help on the concepts and steps I need to take to accomplish the task I detailed above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will your site have any pages other than user pages?  If so, I would suggest placing users in a subdirectory, rather than plugging up the root namespace

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert about .htaccess files but I can explain you how I would do this thing, even if this probably isn't the best solution it should work well anyway.

First, you need to make the profile.php file in a way that it will accept the username instead of the user id as parameter, so something like profile.php?u=username. This is to avoid step 2 since it seems unnecessary to me (if usernames are uniques there's no need to query for the user id).

Then, you write a simple .htaccess rule like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The first two conditions checks if the requested path is not an existing file or directory, the following rule rewrites the URL (if the previous conditions are false, of course)

**NOTE**

I entered a trailing slash because I use another rule which adds a trailing slash to every request which is made (this is to avoid duplicate content having different pages one with and one withouth the slash). This is it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ # check if the URL already ends with a slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Of course you may need to add other conditions if needed, but I guess this is a good general approach to the problem

Comment: Jack, thanks so much for your answer. As much as I appreciate the code you included, which I really do appreciate, what made me want to smack myself was the idea that the username was as unique as the user_id so why not simply change the profile.php page to run from the username instead. I got so into the code of the problem that I completely ignored thinking about the problem rationally.  Thanks again.  You've been a huge help.  A two hour brain meltdown solved in less than ten minutes.  This site is invaluable.  Thanks again.

Comment: I believe this answer, while pointing out some good techniques, is overly complicated and has unnecessary components.  The url should be `http://www.site.com/username` with no trailing slash.  (as he specified above).  That removes the need for the `RewriteCond` and 301 redirects.

Comment: @Michael: You're welcome, I'm glad to help when possible.
@gahooa: Well, this is true, but it is just done to avoid getting 404 errors when a user tries to access site.com/username/ instead of simply site.com/username. This code just accepts both versions

Answer (score 1):

this is a very simple problem (once you know the steps).

Remember that when `mod_rewrite` rewrites a request to a local url, the default behavior is to do it internally.

Therefore, with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  /profile.php?id=$1
```

You will automatically have /profile.php capture the id that was passed.

Since the web client (eg, browser) is none the wiser, whatever you return from that PHP script will be sent **straight back** to the browser with no further issues.

The user will not even know you are using PHP (unless you send a header, and they bother to look).

In the PHP script, it is a simple:

```
<?php
    $id = trim(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '');

    if(empty($id))
    {
       die('User not found');
    }

    // look up in db, etc...
    // render page
```

Comment: Gahooa, Thanks so much for the answer.  Think I'm going to end up trying both suggestions out if only for the learning experience.